# How to specify additional source directory for scaladoc?

Tags: sbt, scaladoc

I have a bit of a nonstandard sbt build setup due to the need to use both Eclipse and sbt.

My sources are in `src/main/scala` and `src/com/companyname/[folder1, folder2, etc]` directories.

How can I set up sbt so it also generates documentation for these additional `folderX` folders under `src/com/companyname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use the following in `build.sbt`:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += sourceDirectory.value
```

`inspect` is your friend.

```
> inspect doc
[info] Task: java.io.File
[info] Description:
[info]  Generates API documentation.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/scaladoc/}scaladoc/compile:doc
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:706
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:doc::configuration
[info]  compile:doc::sources
[info]  compile:doc::apiMappings
[info]  compile:doc::target
[info]  compile:doc::fileInputOptions
[info]  compile:doc::streams
[info]  compile:doc::compilers
[info]  compile:doc::scalacOptions
[info]  compile:doc::dependencyClasspath
[info]  compile:doc::maxErrors
[info]  compile:doc::javacOptions
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:copyDocAssetsTask
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:doc
[info]  *:doc
[info]  {.}/compile:doc
[info]  {.}/*:doc
[info]  */compile:doc
[info]  */*:doc
[info] Related:
[info]  test:doc
```

Under `Dependencies` you'll find that `doc` task depends on `compile:doc::sources` among other things. Use `inspect` again with the setting.

```
> inspect compile:doc::sources
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]
[info] Description:
[info]  All sources, both managed and unmanaged.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/scaladoc/}scaladoc/compile:sources
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:187
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:doc
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:doc::sources
[info]  compile:sources
[info]  *:doc::sources
[info]  *:sources
[info]  {.}/compile:doc::sources
[info]  {.}/compile:sources
[info]  {.}/*:doc::sources
[info]  {.}/*:sources
[info]  */compile:doc::sources
[info]  */compile:sources
[info]  */*:doc::sources
[info]  */*:sources
[info] Related:
[info]  compile:sources
[info]  test:sources
```

Under `Dependencies` you find that it depends on `compile:sources` and following along you find that you should change `unmanagedSourceDirectories` setting to have what you want.